# Propositional Logic Tautology Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have question about a proposition that I need to prove is a tautology:

$((p \rightarrow q) \wedge (q \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$

I have tried negating the first large bracket, but after a few steps I'm stuck. Should I show that the first 2 brackets are the same as $(p \rightarrow r)$ and therefore it is a tautology?

Please help me.

Comment: What are your axioms and inference rules?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer through truth tables,

[image]

This is how I did it:

- Fill in all the variables first.
- Do the first implication from **p** and **q**
- Do the second implication from **q** and **r**
- Do the conjunction from the first and second implications
- Do the implication to the furthest right, from **p** and **r**
- Then do the remaining implication from the conjunction and the implication above.

The end result is that the proposition is true in all possible worlds, a tautology.

Comment: Thanks dude. I needed to use proofs and laws of logic not truth tables. Sorry I should have mentioned that :(. I have solved it now though.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Suppose p->q and q->r.     Assumption for --> introduction

    p-->q                      and elimination
    q-->r                      and elim.

       Suppose p                   assumption for --> int

       q                           --> elim
       r                           --> elim
    p-->r                          --> int
```

(p-->q and  q-->r)-->(p-->r)

Comment: So once we reach $(p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) $ what formula do we use to show their equivalence, or do we just assume they are true?

Comment: Dont worry I've solved it from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that we just showed it was a theorem--that it's derivable from the empty set. It seemed like you wanted to derive it syntactically (which is why I provided the derivation). But technically, tautology has to do with semantics, i.e. truth values, so Qtian may be right in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my solution for others to view.

$((p→q)∧(q→r))→(p→r) \\ \equiv (p \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r) \\
\equiv T$

I think the law is called Hypothetical Syllogism.

Please correct me if its not all right.

Comment: You are using the hypothetical syllogism to prove the hypothetical syllogism. Your argument is circular.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof uses a Fitch-style natural deduction proof checker:

[image]

To show the statement is a tautology, I will attempt to derive it without any premises. If I can do that it would be the same as putting the conditional statement into a [truth table generator](https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html) and showing that all valuations of the sentence letters give a true result under the top-level conditional ($\to$) connective symbol. That would make it a tautology.

Since what I want to prove is a conditional, I assume the antecedent, $(P\to Q) \land (Q\to R)$ as the start of a subproof, indented in Fitch-style natural deduction. Since this antecedent is a conjunction, I use conjunction elimination (∧E) to derive each of the conjuncts on lines 2 and 3.

Since the consequent of what I want to prove is also a conditional, I start another subproof assuming its antecedent, $P$. Given $P$, I can use modus ponens or conditional elimination (→E) on line 5 to derive $Q$ referencing lines 4 and 2. Similarly on line 6 I can derive $R$.

At this point I have a subproof assuming $P$ and deriving $R$. I can summarize that by using conditional introduction (→I) on line 7 to derive $P\to Q$.  This discharges the assumption on line 4 and closes the subproof.  Line 7 gives me the consequent of the conditional I want to derive.

I still have an undischarged subproof starting on line 1, but I note that I can discharge that assumption using conditional introduction on line 8 to derive the goal.

---

The OP has the following question:

> Should I show that the first 2 brackets are the same as (p→r) and therefore it is a tautology?

For the antecedent of this conditional to be the same as the consequent it would have to be a biconditional. This would show more than is required, it if were possible. (One can use a truth table generator to show that the biconditional is not a tautology.)

Rather one has to assume the antecedent and derive the consequent without using any premises. Although one is assuming the antecedent in a subproof, that assumption is later discharged closing the subproof and so one derives the goal without any premises or undischarged assumptions.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/